# How to validate phone number in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, validation, phone-number

I'm currently using phonenumbers package as a validation method to my django's UserCreationForm for its phone number field. In my current code I am using a get method to retrieve the phone number from its field and then do the validation. If the entered number does not exists, a form error is supposed to pop up and state that the number is not in a country's format (in this case i'm using singapore). Please tell me what changes should be made to my current code.

I've tried using **"from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField"** for the phone number validation and it validates the number I've entered, the only problem is that the users will have to type their country code and I cannot have that. I'm using just the phonenumbers package so that users will not have to enter the country code.

```
/* forms.py */
import phonenumbers
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from validate_email import validate_email
from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    # phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
    phone_number = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'phone_number']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        if not validate_email(email, verify=True):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid email")
        return email

    def clean_phone(self):
        phone_number = self.cleaned_data.get("phone_number")
        z = phonenumbers.parse(phone_number, "SG")
        if not phonenumbers.is_valid_number(z):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Number not in SG format")
        return phone_number

/* views.py */
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # user = form.save()
            # phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            # do something with phone number??
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            phone = form.cleaned_data.get('phone_number')
            user.Meta.phone_number = phone
            user.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('blog-home')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

I expect the output to validate the entered phone number in the phone field without its country code and only 8 digits and raise an error if that number does not exist.

Comment: You need to make modifications eithe to your `is_valid_number(z)` or to your `z` variable by adding the code yourself in front of the number before validation. Provide your `is_valid_number(z)` function to help you more.

Comment: You should call your method `clean_phone_number()` otherwise it won't be called. Apart from that, it should work, I've tried your code, works for me.

Comment: I would also make your input field a `CharField` instead of `IntegerField` because people tend to add spaces or dashes in phone numbers. Your validation will take care of cleaning the number: don't `return phone_number`, but `return z.national_number` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your validation looks correct to me, but you're doing two things wrong:

- Rename the method to `clean_phone_number()` instead of `clean_phone`. The field is `phone_number` not `phone`.
- Change the field to a `CharField` instead of `IntegerField` (too restrictive for many users) and `return z.national_number` instead of `phone_number`, that way it's returning the correctly cleaned number before saving. Or whatever format you want to store it in.

Comment: Thank you its working for me, one question tho, can i write the return sentence to "return phonenumbers.format_number(z, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.E164)" instead. It might be better to convert the number to E164 format instead of local format.

Answer (score 1):

Set a field with **"PhoneNumberField()"** in **"models.py"**:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
```

Then, assign **the widget "PhoneNumberPrefixWidget()"** to the field with an initial country code like **initial='US'** in a custom form and assign the custom form to the admin as shown below. *Initial country code must be uppercase:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Contact
from django import forms
from phonenumber_field.widgets import PhoneNumberPrefixWidget

class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {                          # Here
            'phone': PhoneNumberPrefixWidget(initial='US'),
        }

@admin.register(Contact)
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ContactForm
```

Now, with **the initial country code "US" selected**, the field for a phone number is created as shown below so that users don't need to select a country code by themselves:

[image]

Comment: What if the phone number wasn't `US`? What if we don't want to specify the country phone number, we want user to select his own country.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely familiar with these packages but after having a look at the repo code behind them it seems like you could just set the `region` attribute on the `PhoneNumberField` and keep inheriting all of its validation features and prevent the need for users to type in their region?

Something like this?

```py
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    # Does this not work for your case?
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(region="SG")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'phone_number']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        if not validate_email(email, verify=True):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid email")
        return email
```

Comment: Does the region attribute only work for one specific region or all regions? Lets say other than SG, US can type in their numbers as well

Comment: It will only work for the region you specify. Mainly because during the instantiation of the `PhoneNumberField` there is a `validate_region` function that is run. It will raise a ValueError if you pass a region that does not match its predefined list, though it will allow `None`. But not passing a region will automatically try to parse the number which does require a country code otherwise the number is considered invalid. It needs that country code so that it knows which regex to use for which region.

Comment: It goes quite a bit deeper and more complex on how it decides that but this is about as far as I looked into it. Here is a link to where all the phone number metadata for each region is stored. Basically stores patterns and such for each region and it looks to be dynamically loaded in within the module. https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/tree/dev/python/phonenumbers/shortdata