# Django Forms.py Email And Phone Validation

Tags: python, django, validation, contact-form

I have a contact form created with forms.py that I would like to add validation with regular expressions or any built in Django validators for the email and phone fields. The only files I am using are forms.py, views.py, and the html template (there is no models.py for this contact form). If the user enters an incorrect phone number or email, I want to show them a message saying their format is incorrect and that they need to correct their input. The form should not be able to be submitted until the user enters valid data.

Right now entering fake data into the form and then submitting it causes the form to not do anything (it goes to # in the url) but the user has no idea if the email sent or not.

What I have tried below:

#### Forms.py:

```py
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import validate_email
​
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'autocomplete':'off'}), required=True)
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(error_messages={'invalid': 'This is my email error msg.'}, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'autocomplete':'off'}), required=True)
    contact_subject = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'autocomplete':'off'}), required=True)
    contact_phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'autocomplete':'off'}), required=True)
    content = forms.CharField(
    required=True,
    widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'autocomplete':'off'})
    )
​
    # the new bit we're adding
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['contact_name'].label = "Full Name:"
        self.fields['contact_email'].label = "Email:"
        self.fields['contact_subject'].label = "Subject:"
        self.fields['contact_phone'].label = "Phone:"
        self.fields['content'].label = "Message:"
​
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['contact_email']
        validator = RegexValidator("^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$")
        validator(email)
        return email
```

#### Views.py:

```py
def contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm
​
    # new logic!
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)
​
        if form.is_valid():
​
            recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
            url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
            payload = {
                'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
                'response': recaptcha_response
            }
            data = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode()
            req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=data)

            response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
            result = json.loads(response.read().decode())

            print('result:' + str(result))
​
            print('recaptcha_response:' + str(recaptcha_response))
​
            print('result_success:' + str(result['success']))

​
​
            if (not result['success']) or (not result['action'] == 'contact'):
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.')
​
            contact_name = request.POST.get(
                'contact_name'
            , '')
            contact_subject = request.POST.get(
                'contact_subject'
            , '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get(
                'contact_email'
            , '')
            contact_phone = request.POST.get(
                'contact_phone'
            , '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')
​
            # Email the profile with the
            # contact information
            template = get_template('contact_template.txt')
            context = {
                'contact_name': contact_name,
                'contact_email': contact_email,
                'contact_subject': contact_subject,
                'contact_phone': contact_phone,
                'form_content': form_content,
            }
            content = template.render(context)
​
            email = EmailMessage(
                contact_subject,
                content,
                "Your website" +'',
                ['email@gmail.com'],
                headers = {'Reply-To': contact_email }
            )
            email.send()
            messages.info(request, "Your message was sent successfully. Thank you for reaching out.")
​
    return render(request, 'contact.html', {
        'form': form_class,
    })
```

#### Html template:

```html
<form id='cform' action="#" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<KEY>'></script>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<KEY>"></div>
    <script>
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute('<KEY>', {action: 'contact'})
            .then(function(token) {
                ginput = document.createElement('input');
                ginput.type = "hidden";
                ginput.name = "g-recaptcha-response";
                ginput.value = token;
                document.getElementById("cform").appendChild(ginput);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How would I do this using Django only and without JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58006706/how-to-validate-phone-number-in-django

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EmailValidator` instead of `RegexValidator`.  That way you don't need to write a regex that can reliably test email addresses (which is hard to get right).

And to validate a phone number I would use the phonenumbers library.  https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers

**Update**

The Djano forms documentation is very good.  The answers are here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/

I'll give you some pointers.

The example for form handling with class-based views is a contact form.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

and this reference is excellent:

https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/

For the email field everything you are trying to do is handled by defualt.  This is enough:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_email = forms.EmailField()
```

For the phone number, you can write your own validator, referring to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/ and the phonenumbers documentation.  Something like:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
import phonenumbers

def validate_phone_number(value):
    z = phonenumbers.parse(value, None)
    if not phonenumbers.is_valid_number(z):
        raise ValidationError(
            _('%(value) is not a valid phone number'),
            params={'value': value},
        )
```

Then

```
contact_phone = models.CharField(validators=[validate_phone_number])
```

Comment: Can you show me how to implement EmailValidator and the phone numbers github link in my code? That is what I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

A third-party package ([here](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field)) will contain the phone number validation you seek.

```sh
pip install django-phonenumber-field
pip install phonenumbers
```

```py
# forms.py
...
from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField
...

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    ... 
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(
        error_messages={'invalid': 'This is my email error msg.'}, 
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'autocomplete':'off'}), 
        required=True)
    ...
    contact_phone = PhoneNumberField(required=True)
    ...
```

Note also the comment in the project's README:

> Representation can be set by PHONENUMBER_DB_FORMAT variable in django
>   settings module. This variable must be one of 'E164', 'INTERNATIONAL',
>   'NATIONAL' or 'RFC3966'. Recommended is one of the globally meaningful
>   formats 'E164', 'INTERNATIONAL' or 'RFC3966'. 'NATIONAL' format
>   require to set up PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION variable.
>
> The object returned is a PhoneNumber instance, not a string. If
>   strings are used to initialize it, e.g. via
>   MyModel(phone_number='+41524204242') or form handling, it has to be a
>   phone number with country code.

So, you can (presumably, I have not tested this) via these settings configure the form widget to validate phone numbers according to your particular standards. (See the configuration options in the underlying package, [`phonenumbers`](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers#example-usage).

Comment: @meknajirta: Funnily enough, we're back to your original question: how do I implement the `django-phonenumbers` package? :)