# Django Views.py Validate Phone Number

Tags: python, django, validation

I would like to use something like django-phonenumber-field or another method but strictly for views.py to be able to validate or display an error message if the user does not give a valid international phone number in the format of +12125552368 as an example.

This form does not use models.py or forms.py and I would like to keep everything inside of views.py if possible. Also do not want to use JavaScript for security and people disabling it reasons.

Html:
https://dpaste.org/sgyo

Views.py:
https://dpaste.org/vjZZ

How can this be accomplished?

(A follow-up question is here: [Django Forms.py Email And Phone Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59295679/django-forms-py-email-and-phone-validation/59329453#59329453).)

Comment: Why do you not want to use a Form? It would make your form handling and by extension your view a lot cleaner

Comment: There are very few reasons _not_ to use django forms actually.  And by all means split this monstruous thing into readable, manageable, testable functions, and learn to do proper exception handling - a bare except clause around two complex calls which each have hundreds of reasons for failing followed by the assumption that the only reason it would fail is that "the payment has been declined" is about the worst thing you could do.

Comment: @Lain Shelvington and bruno - Okay I see your points. If you so insist, can you help me convert my code to use forms.py instead? If not, can you help me write code to use django-phonenumbers uses python-phonenumbers using the example given below but implementing it using my code? That I am having trouble with.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers I am attempting to do the forms.py now I thought I did everything but the fields are not showing up on the webpage. https://dpaste.org/akbh Can I have some assistance?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers update I got the fields to show up on the webpage but now the form does not submit and the validation errors do not show up on the page. https://dpaste.org/22SV

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I updated my comments below. I am close I just need to figure out the google recaptcha if that works and why the validation is not working. Can you help?

Comment: @meknajirta: " I updated my comments below. I am close I just need to figure out the google recaptcha if that works and why the validation is not working. Can you help?" Post this in a new question. And, this time, it would be much preferred for you to paste your code directly into the Stack Overflow site, rather than dpaste. Split out the parts of the code about which you have questions and format it nicely so readers can respond easily to help you.

Comment: @meknajirta: For the proper way to add your code to Stack Overflow, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`django-phonenumbers` uses `python-phonenumbers`. Since you want to skip the forms and work directly in the view, you can thus skip the Django package altogether; use the Python package. From the docs, here's an example:

```py
>>> import phonenumbers
>>> x = phonenumbers.parse("+442083661177", None)
>>> print(x)
Country Code: 44 National Number: 2083661177 Leading Zero: False
>>> type(x)
<class 'phonenumbers.phonenumber.PhoneNumber'>
>>> y = phonenumbers.parse("020 8366 1177", "GB")
>>> print(y)
Country Code: 44 National Number: 2083661177 Leading Zero: False
>>> x == y
True
>>> z = phonenumbers.parse("00 1 650 253 2222", "GB")  # as dialled from GB, not a GB number
>>> print(z)
Country Code: 1 National Number: 6502532222 Leading Zero(s): False
```

https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers#example-usage

Here's a sketch of what it would look like in your code:

First, install `phonenumbers`: `pip install phonenumbers`.

```html
<form action="." method="post" id="payment-form">
  {% csrf_token %}

  ...

  <label for="phone"> Phone: </label>
  {% if not validated_phone_number %} 
    <input id="phone" name="phone" value="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" type="tel" required />
  {% else %}
    <div id="phone">{{ validated_phone_number }}
  {% endif %}

  ...

</form>
```

```py
# views.py
import phonenumbers

def PaymentView(request):

    ...

    if request.method == "POST":
        ...

        phonenum_input = request.post.get('phone')

        try:
            phonenum = phonenumbers.parse(phonenum_input)
        except phonenumbers.phonenumberutils.NumberParseException:
            messages.warning(
                request, "The phone number is not valid."
            )
            context = {
                'publishKey': publishKey,
                'selected_membership': selected_membership,
                'amend': "true",
                "client_secret": payment_intent.client_secret,
                "STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY": settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
                "subscription_id": stripe_subscription.id
            }

            return render(request, "memberships/3d-secure-checkout.html", context)

        else: # We now assume the number is valid.
            context.update({'valid_phone_number': phonenum})

        ...
            return render(request, "memberships/membership_payment.html", context)
```

(For you, and for others viewing this post, it would indeed be better to use the Django forms library, for the reasons that [bruno-desthuilliers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41316/bruno-desthuilliers) highlights above. Read [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/) from the Django team. Perhaps you, meknajirta, can get this working with my snippets and then move on to following bruno-desthuilliers's suggestions. Post a follow-up question and we'll be happy to help.)

Comment: But yes, as noted in the comments, using Django's Forms would make it easier, unless you have other constraints.

Comment: Thank you for showing me this. I am just not sure how to implement it with my code. Can you show me how? I found this https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/104094/phonenumbers.parse but how do I connect it with the id from the template?

Comment: @meknajirta: I updated the answer to include a sketch of what your code could look like. The post you link to also has good examples. Follow their lead after you have the template and view setup as above.

Comment: Wow thank you for such a detailed response! I got really close using your method. The only thing though is the phone number error message shows up after the payment is made on a completely different part of the website and not the form itself - it does not stop the payment from happening. How can I get the error message to display on the form? In response to your other stuff, sounds like a plan. https://dpaste.org/fefB#L10,11,12,13,14,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180

Comment: I am trying to do the forms.py now but I am having trouble. The form fields are not showing up on the webpage. Can I have some assistance with this as well as the above views.py where we got really close? https://dpaste.org/akbh

Comment: Update I got the fields to show up on the webpage but now the form does not submit and the validation errors do not show up on the page. dpaste.org/22SV

Comment: Update again. I got the form fields to show up on the webpage and it submits to Stripe for payment. However, the google recaptcha print statements do not get printed so I do not know if that works or not and the phone and email validations do not work. I also want to figure out how to pass value="{{ user.email }}" to the email value of forms.py. https://dpaste.org/r2hO Can you help me figure it out?

Comment: @meknajirta: Glad to see you're making some progress! Can I ask a favor? Please split out your questions formally into *new* questions by making a new question post. Many of your questions here would be answered by doing a simple tutorial on forms; I'd say it's time for you to do that. (Doing the process I suggest here would work better with the Stack Overflow processes.) Please also click the checkmark above, next to my answer, to accept it since it worked for you (this will add points ["reputation"] to my account which will unlock features of this site for me).

Comment: Okay I will ask a new question but I have a lot of code which is why I am using dpaste. I will reward you a point on this one. I would appreciate if you can help me with the new question I just posted.